# Getting the VALUE of array dropdown items not ID

Tags: php, drupal

I'm building a select dropdown, when the form submits and emails me, it is submitting that selected dropdowns ID, not the dropdown options 'Value' instead.

```
$result = db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE type =  :type', array(
':type' => 'location',
))->fetchCol();

$items = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $items[] = $value;
}

$form['location'] = array(
    //'#prefix' => print_r($result),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $items,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('search-form'))
);
```

[image]

I tried using the $i++ idea but not too sure if correct.

```
//SELECT LOCATION
$result = db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE type =  :type', array(
':type' => 'location',
))->fetchCol();

$items = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $items[] = $value;
    $++;
}

$form['location'] = array(
    //'#prefix' => print_r($result),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $items[$i],
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('search-form'))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding something here. What you get is the value, that in your case is a number (0, 1, ...). if what you want is set the values the same as the text, you can try this

```
$result = db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE type =  :type', array(
':type' => 'location',
))->fetchCol();

$items = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $items[$value] = $value;
}

$form['location'] = array(
    //'#prefix' => print_r($result),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $items,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('search-form'))
);
```